# is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a favourite button for a recipe application that I'm doing

I'm using an image button and have ran into the error message

```
Error:(19, 65) error: anonymous jbscookbook.example.com.fyp.FavouriteBtn$1 is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener
```

here's my code

recipe.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/jbsbackground2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_detail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/barbecuedporkribs" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_detail"
    android:background="#3D3C3A" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_detail"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Recipe"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/favourites"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFavourite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add To Favourites (click star)"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/favbtn"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/staroff"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:onClick="onClickFavBtn"
            android:clickable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ingredients"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIngredients"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvTD"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvK"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvIngredients"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Preparation"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPreparation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvK"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

FavouriteBtn.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class FavouriteBtn extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipe);

    final ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favbtn);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClickFavBtn(View v) {
            boolean isFavourite = readState();

            if (isFavourite) {
                imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staroff);
                isFavourite = false;
                saveState(isFavourite);

            } else {
                imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staron);
                isFavourite = true;
                saveState(isFavourite);

            }

        }
    });

}

private void saveState(boolean isFavourite) {
    SharedPreferences aSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor aSharedPreferencesEdit = aSharedPreferences
            .edit();
    aSharedPreferencesEdit.putBoolean("State", isFavourite);
    aSharedPreferencesEdit.commit();
}

private boolean readState() {
    SharedPreferences aSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return aSharedPreferences.getBoolean("State", true);
}

}
```

I've tried a lot of different things that I found on the internet but nothing works.

Could someone help me in how to fix this problem and show me where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class FavouriteBtn extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe);

        final ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favbtn);
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                

                boolean isFavourite = readState();

                if (isFavourite) {
                    imgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.staroff);
                    saveState(false);
                } else {
                    imgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.staron);
                    saveState(true);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void saveState(boolean isFavourite) {
        SharedPreferences aSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor aSharedPreferencesEdit = aSharedPreferences
                .edit();
        aSharedPreferencesEdit.putBoolean("State", isFavourite);
        aSharedPreferencesEdit.commit();
    }

    private boolean readState() {
        SharedPreferences aSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return aSharedPreferences.getBoolean("State", true);
    }

}
```

---

Simply remove:

```
android:onClick="onClickFavBtn"
```

from your XML `ImageButton`

and change `onClickFavBtn` to `onClick` in listener.

Comment: thanks for your answer, when i do what you have suggested the button is no longer clickable and doesn't change colours when clicked

Comment: when i try your first suggestion i just noticed under if (isFavourite) it says "isFavourable is always fales" and "isFavourable is always true". I tried what you just suggested and it does not work i receive a lot of error messages and if i don't make imgButton final i get the message "Variable imgButton is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final"

Comment: @john Check my edit now. I have removed warning which you mentioned, also, change method to `setImageResource()`.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, i copied your edit and pasted it in to my code and it's gotten rid of "isFavourable is always false" and "isFavourable is always true" but the star is still not clickable and doesn't change colour :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have added the click functionality in xml. In that case you don't have to attach the click listener to the button. Listener implementation is required only if you haven't added the click functionality in xml. Use either of the approach, not both together.

**Solution 1**

Change

```
imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClickFavBtn(View v) {
        boolean isFavourite = readState();

        if (isFavourite) {
            imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staroff);
            isFavourite = false;
            saveState(isFavourite);

        } else {
            imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staron);
            isFavourite = true;
            saveState(isFavourite);

        }

    }
});
```

to (just remove the listener attaching part)

```
public void onClickFavBtn(View v) {
        boolean isFavourite = readState();

        if (isFavourite) {
            imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staroff);
            isFavourite = false;
            saveState(isFavourite);

        } else {
            imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staron);
            isFavourite = true;
            saveState(isFavourite);

        }
    }
```

**Solution 2**

Remove `android:onClick="onClickFavBtn"` from xml and

Change

```
public void onClickFavBtn(View v) {
```

to

```
public void onClick(View v) {
```